# uitableview + navigation controller set title from selected element

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINnavigationController` that handles the navigation in a `UITableView`.

When I select a row from the table I need to display in the `UINavigationController` title the selected item from the previous menu.

The label of the cell is read from an external `xml` that fills the rows of the `UITableView`.

How can I display my selection on the title of the `UINavigationBar`?

I've set a static title by using the `self.title` command, but it doesn't fit my needs

Comment: SOLVED: it was a problem given by the coredata entity.
solved with self.title = [selectedObject valueForKey: @"name"];

Answer (score 5):

Would this work for you?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    DetailTableViewController *detailController = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    //   Set the detail controller title to whatever you want here...
    detailController.title = @"Your title";

    //   Or set it to the title of this row
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailController.title = cell.textLabel.text;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It works when I call a detailview, but my app works in this way:
Table1->Table2->Table3->DetailView
from Table3 to DetailView i have no problem, it works excatly like you suggested. I want to display the selection on table1 as title in table2 etc etc...

Comment: Right, the code sample was meant to be illustrative.  It should work the same way from table1->table2, then table2->table3.  In each `UITableViewController` subclass in that hierarchy, you can populate the next controller's `title` property in this same fashion.

Answer (score 5):

Normaly the `UINavigationController` always picks out the `title` of the `UIViewController` which has been actually loaded. Thats why you have to define it inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.title = @"Title";
```

The method displayed above seems to be more dynamic...but this also works.