# How to open a navigation controller with the title of the cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like a navigation controller to open when a table cell is selected. The navigation controller must have the title of the text contained in the cell selected.

I think I am very close with my code, but cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Nothing opens when I select on a cell from the table.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        myCell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        // Get the stock to be shown
        let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
        // Configure our cell title made up of name and price


        let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")


        print(titleStr)
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

        return myCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
        let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")

        print(titleStr)

    }

     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "customerDetails" {

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as UIViewController
        let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        destinationVC.navigationItem.title = myCell.textLabel!.text
        }
    }

}
```

**NEW UPDATE:**

**THE FOLLOWING NOW WORKS:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    // Get the stock to be shown
    let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
    // Configure our cell title made up of name and price

    let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")

    print(titleStr)
    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailController")
    controller.title = titleStr
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}
```

But I need the view controller to present itself as a Show Detail storyboard style, where the detailController overlays the FirstViewController.

Where you can't go back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uitableview + navigation controller set title from selected element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670797/uitableview-navigation-controller-set-title-from-selected-element)

Comment: I think it's possible duplicate from this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670797/uitableview-navigation-controller-set-title-from-selected-element

Answer (score 1):

Check if the segue is connected in the main.storyboard file. If it is, check the identifier matches the one in the code. If that does not work it might be because you are making a new cell in the prepareForSegue and to fix that you have to create a global variable for each cell. If all of it does not work tell me. Can you attach the main.storyboard file.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a global variable, but everything else is correct. I think I am passing the cell value (text in cell) incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is best to just push the view controller programmatically. An extremely simple full example would look like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let titles: [String] = ["First", "Second", "Third"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let controller = UIViewController() // or UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "whateverIdentifierISetInStoryboard")
        controller.title = titles[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

}
```

So using `navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)` is a method that will show a new view controller with animation right-to-left.

A title is simply set on the view controller directly which can be created from storyboard using `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "whateverIdentifierISetInStoryboard")`.

This assumes that this view controller is actually already on the navigation controller.

If you truly need to do this with segues then you need to manually call the segue using identifiers. You also send your title as a `sender` parameter.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customerDetails", sender: titles[indexPath.row])
```

In your case probably something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
    let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customerDetails", sender: titleStr)
}
```

Now just use this title:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "customerDetails" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as UIViewController
        destinationVC.title = sender as? String
    }
}
```

Another approach is to save the current title on a property and then use it when segue is prepared:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
    let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")
    self.nextScreenTitle = titleStr
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customerDetails", sender: self)
}
```

And then usage:

```
var nextScreenTitle: String?
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "customerDetails" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as UIViewController
        destinationVC.title = nextScreenTitle
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors but the title just does not show up in the navigation controller title

Comment: @RelsonJames My apology. The `prepareForSegue` method has been renamed in latest Swift. Please check my updated answer. You need to use `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {`

Comment: It still does not show up, could it be that the text from the cell is not being passed correctly?

Comment: @RelsonJames There is a chance that your string is `nil` or empty. Try to confirm this. I suggest you put a breakpoint inside `prepare(for segue` (You press left of the code on a line and a blue bullet should show). When you run your project it should stop at that line and you can inspect all values. Furthermore you can at that point use your console (bottom right part of Xcode) to print values you have access to. You usually use "po" to print your object. In your case try "po sender as? String". This should give you the string you have created. If it is nil then check it at `performSegue`.

Comment: The sender: titleStr is correctly defined in performSegue but is nil in destinationVC.tlte = sender as? String

Comment: @RelsonJames that seems a bit strange. You did insert it into method, right? `sender: titleStr`. If you did then I may need more information on what goes on. I replicated your scenario and it seems to work for me. There is always another way though. Since your cell is selected you could recreate the string in your method as well. Instead of `indexPath` you would need `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!`. Or alternative add another property to which you set your string on cell selected and then use it in prepare for segue.

Comment: Just to clarify what do mean insert it into method?

Comment: @RelsonJames just to confirm that you did insert it as a last parameter here `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customerDetails", sender: titleStr)`. That it isn't for instance `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customerDetails", sender: nil)`

Comment: @RelsonJames Is there a chance for me to glance at the project? I believe you can find my email in my profile.

Comment: I've actually decided to take your advice and try to not use segues and just simplify everything

Comment: The issue I have now is the storyboard option does not load and instead crashes the app. By story board option I mean using UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "whateverIdentifierISetInStoryboard")

Comment: The programmatic way works fine and the title is passed correctly, but I would rather use the storyboard method becasue I have everything designed there

Comment: @RelsonJames Yes well I am sure it must be a silly bug that you don't get that string into your method but I would need to look deeper into what is happening. I edited the answer to give another solution though. Maybe try that one.

Comment: I appreciate it, one last thing when using UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "whateverIdentifierISetInStoryboard") the app crashes. I need to use the storyboard version not the programmatic approach. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @RelsonJames What does the crash log say? It usually outputs something into the console. You do need to insert appropriate identifiers there. The storyboard name must be correct as well. So you need to check that the storyboard "Main" is the same as file name of your storyboard and "whateverIdentifierISetInStoryboard" must equal to the identifier of the view controller you set in the storyboard; it is under "Storyboard ID".

Comment: Yes I made sure both are equal, but how does is the table value being passed into the storyboard controller if we are getting rid of “let controller =“ ? I’m assuming we don’t right it because you said or

Comment: @RelsonJames this `segue.destination` gives you the reference to your view controller. So it is the same.

Comment: I posted an update, again I really appreciate your help. This time I got everything to work correctly, except for the controller presenting a Show Detail style (where the controller goes over the view controller that triggers it). How can this be done? I show the code I use in the update

Answer (score 1):

You should use **variable** in **deistinationVC** then in **ViewDidLoad** use "navigationItem.title"

In **firstViewController**:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "customerDetails" {

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as UIViewController
    let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    destinationVC.navTitle = myCell.textLabel!.text
    }
}
```

And **SecondViewController** :

```
class secondViewcontroller : UIViewController{

  var navTitle = string()

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    navigationItem.title = navTitle

   }
```

Comment: Dont forget to define "var navTitle = string()" in distinationVC

Comment: use push to navigate >> let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customerDetails") as! customerDetailsVC .  and >> vc.navTitle = titleStr and >> navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Answer (score 1):

do this in your update version

```
let controller = storyboard.instantiateviewcontroller(withIdentifier: "youridentifier") as? "name of your view controller"
navigationController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```